# after package with maven, there is no jar generated in Idea.the error is: File encoding has not been set

Tags: java, maven

after package with maven, there is no jar generated in Idea.the error is: File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @  
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources,       i.e. build is platform dependent!

Comment: What you're showing is not an error. It is a warning. Look for errors in your log.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open this setting and the problem is fixed:  **show excluded files.**
Actually,the jars are generated,but it just doesn't show on idea.

Comment: I fixed it by myself

Answer (score 2):

You can add encoding to your pom.xml files

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```